# EWS Managed API, Why Item.DateTimeSent.Millisecond is always zero?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am trying to calculate the time taken to send email message and time taken to receive email message. i am using EWS in my program , I set streaming notification to receive call back when a new mail reaches reciptent mailbox .

once received notification i bind the Itemevent with ews service , i checked the item properties DateTimeCreated, DateTimeSent, DateTimeReceived.All these properties are of DateTime object.

I checked DateTimeSent milisecond is always 0, whereas DateTimeCreated, DateTimeReceived has millisecond value.

I couldnot figure out why DateTimeSent millisecond is always 0 everytime. if i want to claulate time taken from send to receive what should i do.

DateTimeReceived - Datetimesent is the actual time taken to send and receive the message?

or what is the correct way to calculate time taken to  send and receive the message?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a normal date value, but its precision is to the second, rather than the millisecond?

Comment: Precision set Milliseconds but still cant find millisecond in DateTimeSent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set DateTimePrecision as Milliseconds

```
   ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);
    service.Url = new Uri(ConfigSettings.EmailConnectionUrl);
    service.DateTimePrecision = DateTimePrecision.Milliseconds;
```

Comment: Just awesome. Little more light, the condition check greater than less than happens at millisecond level but displayed at seconds level.

Answer (score 0):

how about actually measuring the `Timespan`?  so for example showing total milliseconds but you could change that to suit

```
var result=((TimeSpan)(DateTimeReceived  - DateTimeSent )).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.00") + "ms";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the EWS Managed API the ExchangeService class has a precision property that you need to set before you make any calls see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.datetimeprecision(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you for answer but its not work for my case i already set this but still cant find millisecond in DateTimeSent

Comment: If you enable tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633676(v%3Dexchg.80) and look at the XML coming from and To the server that should tell you what is happening.